Why is the last bereita in Avot often said before Kaddish?
In many minyanim I have attended there is often some form of torah learning after prayers have been completed and then someone (usually the teacher conducting the learning) will recite the last bereita of Avot
רַבִּי חֲנַנְיָא בֶּן עֲקַשְׁיָא אוֹמֵר, רָצָה הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא לְזַכּוֹת אֶת יִשְׂרָאֵל, לְפִיכָךְ הִרְבָּה לָהֶם תּוֹרָה וּמִצְוֹת, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (ישעיה מב) ה' חָפֵץ לְמַעַן צִדְקוֹ יַגְדִּיל תּוֹרָה וְיַאְדִּיר
before the mourners kaddish is said.
I would like to understand if this practice, ie saying the last bereita in Avot before mourners kaddish is recited, is brought down in the halachic literature and if so, what is the reason that this bereita was chosen to be recited as opposed to any other teaching of Hazal?

Do you mean the "last mishna in makkot"?

See the following passage extracted from https://outorah.org/p/4589/ The Five Types of Kaddish by Rabbi Jack Abramowitz
The Rabbis’ Kaddish (“Kaddish D’Rabbanan”) is recited after a public lecture in the Oral Torah. There is an opinion that the primary practice is to recite this Kaddish after learning Aggadah, the non-legal portions of the Talmud or Midrash. This is based on Sotah 49a, which tells us that since the Temple was destroyed, the world endures because of the recitation of Kedusha in Uva L’Tziyon and the “yehei shmei rabbah” in the Kaddish after Aggadah. Accordingly, the practice has become to recite the Aggadic passage of “Rabbi Chananya…” (Makkos 23b) between a public Torah lecture and Kaddish. Since it is related to Torah study, the Rabbis’ Kaddish includes a passage on behalf of “the Jews, the teachers, their students, their students’ students, and all those who engage in the study of Torah.”
The opinion that Kaddish D’Rabbanan is said after learning a piece of Aggadah is that of the Mishna Berurah at 54:9 https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.54?lang=bi
או אחר תפלה וכמו שכתבנו בס"ק הקודם וכן אחר שלמד איזה ענין מתורה שבע"פ יוכל לומר קדיש דרבנן ועיין במ"א שמסיק דדוקא אם אמר אח"ז עכ"פ מקצת דבר אגדה ואז יוכל לומר הקדיש דרבנן כי עיקר הקדיש זה נתקן על דבר אגדה וע"כ מנהג כל ישראל לומר אחר פרקי אבות ואחר במה מדליקין המאמר דר' חנניא בן עקשיא או אר"א א"ר =אמר רבי= חנינא ת"ח מרבים שלום וכו'. ולפ"ז יש ליזהר כשלומדים משניות יאמרו בסוף הלימוד המאמר דר' חנניא בן עקשיא וכדומה כדי שיהיו יוכלו לומר עי"ז אח"כ הקדיש דרבנן
and the custom is mentioned of reciting either the Rabbi Chananya passage (Makkot 23b) or Rabbi Eleazar said in the name of Rabbi Hanina who said: "The disciples of the sages [talmidei chachamim] increase peace in the world .." (Berachot 64a)

"what is the reason that this bereita was chosen to be recited as opposed to any other teaching of Hazal"

I have answered the first part of the two part question: "I would like to understand if this practice, ie saying the last bereita in Avot before mourners kaddish is recited, is brought down in the halachic literature"

If you like my answer, please consider accepting it. Otherwise, please comment on how it can be improved.
